# Why do I get Run-time error '3011' with ms-access transfertext export?

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

Trying/failing to get DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim to work.  Here's the code...

```
Public Sub Dump_TaskDB_TXT()
 DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Export-BurnDownMetrics", "BurnDownMetrics", "C:\Users\dgauthie\Desktop\BDM.txt"
End Sub
```

I get...

```
Run-time error '3011'
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'BDM#txt'.  
Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path
name correctly.  (etc...) "
```

No, the '#' in 'BDM#txt' is not a typo.  No idea why it's replacing the '.' with '#', but maybe that's a clue as to what's wrong ?

Why would it be complaining about not being able to "find" the file when my intent is to create it ?  I would think that the file should not exist before attempting to export to it.  Yes?  No?

I don't believe there's anything wrong with the export spec.  It worked fine when I created it.

Addendum to this post:
The export spec appears in MSysIMEXSpec with these columns/values:

```
DateDelim:  /
DateFourDigitYear:  -1
DateLeadingZeros:  0
DateOrder:  2
DecimalPoint:  .
FieldSeparator:  |
FileType:  1252
SpecId: Export-BurnDownMetrics
SpecType:  1
StartRow:  0
TextDelim:  "
TimeDelim:  :
```

Comment: The error msg may be misleading. How did you create the export spec? [This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-the-details-of-an-import-or-export-operation-as-a-specification-6b94e183-2b10-4333-a31a-001fe75321b5) is not an export specification that can be used with `DoCmd.TransferText`, you need these ones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36224726/3820271

Comment: Thank You Andre for your reply.  Initially, I did fall into the "import steps" trap.  It became obvious when there was no entry in the MSysIMEXSpecs table.  Eventually I figured that out and there is now an entry in that table.  I will add the content above as an addendum.  I believe/suspect that the problem may have to do with the target filename in that if I remove the ".txt", I get a different error message... "Run-time error '3027': Cannot update. Database or object is read only.".

Comment: Hmm, I remember that `DoCmd.TransferText` can have a will on its own. Try exporting to `file.csv` instead of `file.txt`.

Comment: Nope... "Run-time error '3011':  etc..." .   What's up with the "#" in "BDM#csv" ?  Why is it translating the "." I specified with "#" ?  "#" seems to be allowed in Windows filenames, so that's not it.  Maybe it wants to create as BDM.txt but then loks for it as BDM#txt and then reports the error.  Thinking along those lines, I specified "BDM#txt".  Same error.  Then I tried "BDM..txt" and it reports it can't find "BDM##txt".  When I specify no extention (just "BDM"), I get a 3027 error, "Cannot update Database or object is read-only" .  Weird.

Comment: So is there another way, in vb, that I can... 1) query this access DB  2) open a flat file somewhere  3) write the results to the flat file ?  IOW, bypass this difficult to use "DoCmd.TransferText" feature ?  If so, a strong hint on how to do this would be appreciated.  I'm a linux guy who can hardly spell vb :-)

Comment: This was just bumped and sounds like your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369105/transfer-text-in-ms-access-not-working-engine-could-not-find-the-object

Comment: Yep, that did it.  I recreated the spec and it works now.  Thanks for that pointer !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer Text in MS Access not working ("engine could not find the object")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369105/transfer-text-in-ms-access-not-working-engine-could-not-find-the-object)

Answer (score -2):

Was driving me CRAZY, then I deleted the schema.ini file and had no further problems.

mlocorders = mDataLoc + "QBorders.csv"

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "QBImportQuery", mlocorders, True

Answer (score -2):

I scoured the web and everyone has a different solution that didn't really work for me. So to all the pour souls that have to deal with this stupid error, before DoCmd.TransferText etc etc, add to your code:

If Dir(whateverisyourfilename) <> "" Then

```
    Kill whateverisyourfilename

End If
```

Make sure that the right directory is specified in "whateverisyourfilename".